# JSON / JavaScript get object keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm extracting data from as follows -

The above function returns data in the below format -

```
[Object { date=Date,  value=112,  volume=1469}, Object { date=Date,  value=124,  volume=539}, Object { date=Date,  value=114,  volume=859}, Object { date=Date,  value=123,  volume=1284}, Object { date=Date,  value=113,  volume=1382}, Object { date=Date,  value=129,  volume=1353}]
```

I would like to obtain the list of keys only as a simple array.(Parsing the first object in the array is enough to get this as all other objects have the same keys) In case of the above output, I would like the simple array to look as `["date","value","volume"]`

I tried `JSON.stringify` & then parse but it still doesn't work.

Also, how could I convert the whole array obtained from the chart into a simple array please?

I'm visualizing an output of the below type -

```
[{'date':'whatever',  'value':126,  'volume':911},
{'date':'whatever',  'value':136,  'volume':1005},
{'date':'whatever',  'value':125,  'volume':720}]
```

If the question doesn't make sense, please let me know. I'll see how best I could re-word.

Comment: How are you getting the string , I mean the data?

Comment: What you have there isn't valid JavaScript or JSON. Showing how you extracted that data from the chart might help someone answer.

Comment: if it is an array then just use [`data[0].keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) then you'll get array of keys.

Comment: I've just updated the question with the function that retrieves data from the chart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function. Here in the response from function you get an array. Use that to get the list of keys.

```
var data = getChartData('param')
Object.keys(data[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you Rejith. I did this - `var chartData = getChartData("chartdiv");
var keysOnly = chartData[0].keys();
console.log(keysOnly);` I get the error - `TypeError: chartData[0].keys is not a function`. Sounds like I'm missing including a library?

Comment: It's `Object.keys` not `Object.prototype.keys`. That would need to be called like `Object.keys( data[0] );` . `data[0].keys()` will just throw an error because `data[0].keys` is `undefined|.

Comment: Cool. Thank you Paul & Rejith. Awesome stuff. Thank you tons.

Comment: @Paulpro I cant believe that I made such a silly mistake. Updated.

Comment: Oh One last thing if I can request please -  Also, how could I convert the whole array obtained from the chart into a simple array please? - I'd like the whole data set returned by `getChartData` to be converted to key/value pair

Comment: @usert4jju7 well, that is an array of objects. I you really don't need to convert it. Because if you change it key valuer pair, how do you think the output will be?

Comment: Hmm. I may be wording it incorrect. Basically I'd like it look like what I've updated in the question now. I see the word object in the array which makes me think it's an array of objects whereas, the visualization is more a string type array I guess. Is this my misconception?

Comment: @usert4jju7 just try one thing `JSON.stringify(getChartData('element'))` try this in console. I believe you'll see what you are trying to get. My understanding is that the data is in the form in which you are trying to get.

Comment: Cool. This helps. Thank you Rejith.

Comment: Hello Rejith - Further to this, I've been trying a few other things which I'm stuck with. This solution helped me progress quite a distance but have stumbled on another problem. The question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500656/gropby-using-underscore-js. If you think you would like to help me, please do have a look. This would be highly helpful to me please.

Comment: Dude!  I was searching for an hour trying to figure out why myObject.keys() was giving me "myObject.keys is not a function" even though it is type "object" and was going crazy, but this works great, so big thanks!!!